Relation between Fourier series and Schur polynomials
I would like to know how to express the Fourier series of a symmetric function, $f(\theta_1,...,\theta_N)$, in terms of Schur polynomials $s_\lambda(x_1,...,x_N)$ in the variables $x_j=e^{i\theta_j}$.
The obvious difficulty is that the Fourier series has negative powers. This might be circumvented by defining the extended alphabet $(x_1,...,x_N,y_1,...,y_N)$ with $y_j=x_j^{-1}$. However, a function which is symmetric in the $\theta$'s is not necessarily symmetric in the extended alphabet (if $f$ is real and even, I think it will have hyperoctahedral symmetry).
So, is there some nice relation between Fourier series and Schur polynomials? Or do we need some other family of symmetric polynomials?
